# How to use windowing functions to find gaps in sequences grouped by a column, in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table structure which has 2 columns: `client_id`, `order_no`, and both are integers. I'd like to find gaps in `order_no` in the data so that, for example, for a table containing these rows:

```
42, 1
43, 1
42, 2
43, 5
43, 6
42, 3
```

the output contains the `client_id`, and boundaries of the gaps, like this:

```
43, 2, 4
```

Note that there's no row with `client_id=42` because there are no gaps in its data.

I've tried this for the core part of the query:

```
select 
    client_id, 
    order_no as start_order_no, 
    lead(order_no) over (order by client_id, order_no) as end_order_no
```

but that apparently doesn't do what I want, and I suspect it's because of `client_id` in the OVER part.

Comment: You probably meant `partition by client_id order by order_no`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a CTE or a subquery to get the lead `order_no` first.

> ```
> select client_id,
>        order_no + 1 as c1,
>        no - 1 c2
> from   (select client_id, 
>                order_no,
>                lead(order_no) 
>                    over (partition by client_id order by client_id, order_no) as no
> from     tbl) ct
> where  no is not null
> and    no - order_no > 1;
> ```

> ```
> with ct as
> (
> select   client_id, 
>          order_no,
>          lead(order_no) 
>              over (partition by client_id order by client_id, order_no) as no
> from     tbl
> )
> select client_id,
>        order_no + 1 as c1,
>        no - 1 c2
> from   ct
> where  no is not null
> and    no - order_no > 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> client_id | c1 | c2
> --------: | -: | -:
>        43 |  2 |  4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ee9ded8b710566ed28d284628607e900)*